# Timeouts when typing the computer name into Remote Destktop client connection dialog

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have got a curious problem with Remote Desktop on Windows 10 (on both computers). I run the Remote Desktop client and start typing the name of the remote computer I want to connect to. After every character the dialog freezes for several seconds. Only after that time I can type the next character. This occurs after each character of the computer name.

Once the connection is established, everything works normal.

It's as if the client tries to do a lookup for the computer name and that takes several seconds.

Anybody got an idea what could cause this phenomenon?

Comment: What kind of traffic do you see in Wireshark? Some sort of DNS queries, or LDAP searches?

Comment: I haven't looked for network traffic yet. I hoped that this is a known problem with an also known fix.